# Android app that already exists on iphone

Tags: android, iphone

Can I develop an android app that already exists on iphone market(not by me of course). This is basically stealing the idea, but is this legal?

What do i need to check and where. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you can. I don't recommend it though.

Comment: you should ask this somewhere else check http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Thanks for the response. Like Shazam and SoundHound are basically the same app but they dont infringe upon each others copyright(if they have one). I m only a part time/hobby developer so i dont want to go into lawyers as this involves money. So i seek guidance here. So should i ask the app developer if he has a copyright or NDA of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

Quick disclaimer - I Am Not A Lawyer. Go ask one before you actually do any of these things, to make sure.

That depends on your definition of what "the same app" means.

1. The same idea - this is probably legal, unless the idea is patented. There may be some cost to you if your customer base disapproves of the copying.
2. The same name and/or branding and/or art assets - this is many kinds of illegal. Copying art assets that are owned by the original app's creator is copyright infringement. Copying the name or logo of the original app is trademark infringement - you would be impersonating the other app's authors.

Long story short, it's probably okay to remake an iPhone app for Android as long as you don't copy any code or art assets and don't try to fool users into thinking that you are the same person that made the original app. To stay on the safe side, you should try to make your app cosmetically different from the original to avoid copyright claims on the visual design.

Comment: I have no idea of copying the app(name logo, etc). i only want to use its baxic features in my app. If i make this app and i do infringe upon some copyright, what are the consequences???

Comment: See here for more detailed legal information: http://itlaw.wikia.com/wiki/Copyright_infringement

Comment: Keep in mind that copyright in general doesn't defend ideas, only the particular expression of an idea. The real thing to watch out for is to make sure you don't directly copy any source code (even if you're going to modify it), any images (even if you're going to make extensive changes to them), or any user-visible text.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of factors. This involves copyright and IP  law. Consult a good lawyer who is well versed in these matters.

Answer (score 0):

> This is basically stealing the idea, but is this legal?

**Yes**, But I will still recommand you to Do little R&D stuff for Checking about `Non-Disclosure Agreement (or NDA)` which will prevent you from stealing the idea. or they have `Hire an attorney`.

About `Non-Disclosure Agreement (or NDA)`

According to Me, There is nothing wrong in it. But  if the **Developer of that app has spending time signing, scanning, and sending an NDA to App Store**

then As `NDA(Non-Disclosure Agreement)` is signed Developer has prevent it from stealing the idea by any other **`you can not able to copy it`**.

About `Hire an attorney`

if Developer don’t like the NDA suggested by the developer or they are not comfortable about the process?  **they can Hire an attorney to get advise about your rights and how to protect them.** then also  **`you can not able to copy it`**.

**Finally, Yes you can Go ahead but you have to go through with above suggestions first and Make Sure it is not the case. and If it has, then either think of something else or find a unique selling point in your app that will make it stand out from the crowd.**

Comment: Thanks for the response. Like Shazam and SoundHound are basically the same app but they dont infringe upon each others copyright(if they have one). I m only a part time/hobby developer so i dont want to go into lawyers as this involves money. So i seek guidance here. So should i ask the app developer if he has a copyright or NDA of any kind.